# Extract values from String/"Json"

Tags: python, json, string, list

I have this string but I need to extract specific values from the string/json.

```
{"Artigo":{"NrReg":"81846","Cod":"XXX96000051","Desc_Web":"XX 296 00 BLACK","Desc_Agregadora":"XX 296","PVO":"69","NlDes":"3","Cat1_GrpArtigos":"\t2","Cat2_SegMarca":"s\t0","Cat3_SegAcessorios":{},"Cat4_Categoria":{},"Marca":{},"Attr_Sexo":{},"Attr_MatGenerico":{},"Attr_TipoOculo":{},"Profile_V":"1","Profile_S":"0","StockQty":"0","Image":"XXX96000051.jpg","ImageF":{}}}
```

I have this code in Python 3.7 to extract this string from URL, then I need to get some values, for example from "Cod" is "XXX96000051"

Code:

```
import requests
import time
import json

url = "http://www.urlsite.test"
data = requests.get(url)
result = data.json()


print(result)
t0 = time.time()

for i in result:
    print(i[0])

print("Total time " + str(time.time() - t0) + " sec")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should access values of a dict via keys, so to get the value of the key `Cod`, which is nested under the key `Artigo`, you should use:

```
result['Artigo']['Cod']
```